# How to know if a Spinner is displayed or is no longer displayed

Tags: android, spinner

Is there a callback/method I can use to tell is a Spinner is displayed?
And is there a callback/method I can use to tell when the Spinner is no longer displayed?

setOnItemSelectedListener/onItemSelected is called when an item from the list is selected - but is there any method/callback when the list is removed because the user touches outside the list?

Comment: So you want a listener, when your list changes? Like a cell is removed or added?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by creating your custom spinner ,

after create your layout , you should use it in your layout ,

// com.talha.examples is package name

**mySpinner.java**

```
package com.talha.examples;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class mySpinner extends Spinner {
    Context context;

    public mySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);

        if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "VISIBLE NOW", 1000).show();

        if(visibility == View.GONE)
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "HAS GONE", 1000).show();
    }
}
```

**activity_main_spinner.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.talha.examples.mySpinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#ffffaa" >

    </com.talha.examples.mySpinner>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity .java**

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    com.talha.examples.mySpinner mySpinner;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_spinner);

    mySpinner = (com.talha.examples.mySpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mySpinner.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: it will call when `mySpinner's` visibility changed

Comment: I tried that .... but it didn't work. When the activity (that contains the spinner) is first displayed onVisibilityChanged is called with visibility = 4, then onVisibilityChanged is called with visibility = 0. When the dropdown list is displayed then this method is not called at all. I want to know when the list is displayed, and when the list is no longer displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ... but this shows/hides the spinner, it does not tell me when the list is displayed. I have a Spinner in the layout for my activity. Then when this is touched it displays a list. I want to know when the list is displayed (and when it is no longer displayed).

Comment: Not the solution at all

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to determine when the spinner menu was displayed, and dismissed as well. After a lot of searching, there wasn't a lot of good solutions. I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

1. Created a custom spinner class, and override the following method:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean performClick() {
   this.isDropDownMenuShown = true; //Flag to indicate the spinner menu is shown
       return super.performClick();
   }
   ```
2. In my Activity, override the method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus). If hasFocus == true && the flag in #1 is set to true, then the spinner has been dismissed (can be either by selection or tapping outside the spinner).

   ```
   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   if (actionBarSpinner.isDropdownShown() && hasFocus) {
       actionBarSpinner.setDropdownShown(false);
       //Do you work here
   }
   ```

   }

Good luck!